# Openlayers Vector Feature Popup

Tags: openlayers-2, features, layers, markers

im trying to create a popup in Openlayers that would open when someone clicks a marker. And the marker is setup like this: `new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector()` and not with the ordinary marker layer.

The marker is then placed inside another layer `vesselLayer.addFeatures([markerLayer])`

which is then added to the map: `map.addLayer([vesselLayer])`

Now, How can i get a popup to show when someone selects one of the markers?

Let it be noted that each vesselLayer has only 1 marker. But there can be a 100 dynamically added vesselLayers to the map. (Made it that way for easy access trough the LayerSwitcher).

I tried reading the docs: 
http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/select-feature-openpopup.html

But i could not figgure it out.

The error that comes out of the console is saying that it cannot read the property "events" of null..
I double checked the object instantiation and it does get instantiated and the property is a part of the name.

Heres the object logged out right after instantiation.

[image: Object Overview]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to use following code.

```
   vesselLayer.addMarker(marker);
   vesselLayer.events.register("click", vesselLayer, function(evt){
   popup = new OpenLayers.Popup("chicken",
                   evt.lonlat,
                   new OpenLayers.Size(200,200),
                   "My Content",
                   true);

   map.addPopup(popup);
```

i hope it helps you...

Comment: Gives me basicly the same error as when i tried using the documentation: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'events' of null `

Comment: The error says everything :  `of null` tells the `vesselLayer` is not initialized. Have you checked where you do `vesselLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Markers( "Marks" ); map.addLayer(vesselLayer);` ??

Comment: By the way : why you need a layer with a single feature for each mark ? Follow @Aragon code to have various features in a unique layer with a popup.

Comment: So i found out i had taken a wrong approach to this. I was adding Layer upon Layer, which would make one layer overlay another and kinda block the click events. So i created one single layer with just the features. And then using @Aragon 's Code to make it clickable! Thanks :)